# Windows Mobile SDK : how to turn a label/button into a website link?

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

I am programming in Windows Mobile SDK 6 using Visual Basic, i would like to know how to make a button open the smartphone browser with a specific website path (make a link)

I got to the next piece of code so far:

```
 Public Class GuitarHelperPage
 Public link As New WebBrowser
 Public adress As Uri


 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    Handles Button1.Click

     adress = New Uri("https://www.google.com")

     Try
         link.Navigate(adress)
         'link.Focus()

     Catch ex As System.UriFormatException
         Return
     End Try

 End Sub
```

(the commented 'link.Focus()' its just something i tryed out, but i got the same output)

I simply want to click the button and open the browser at google homepage. But when I click it, the warning "This page contains both secure and nonsecure items. Do you want to continue?" appears and when I click "yes", nothing else hapens.

I've been researching and found this on MSDN help pages:

"The WebBrowser class can only be used in threads set to single thread apartment (STA) mode. To use this class, ensure that your Main method is marked with the STAThreadAttribute attribute"

SO i added this my main method:

```
<STAThread()> _
 Shared Sub Main()
```

But still i get this error : "Type STAThread is not defined." And can't find a away around, I tried to add this same attribute to a Windows Desktop VB project and it works, maybe there is another way to do it in Mobile?

I am using .Net Framework 3.5 and windows mobile sdk 6.0 for this project

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the default browser, you don't need a WebBrowser control.  Just use the `Process` class, specifically the [`Start` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that takes in a `ProcessStartInfo`.  Set the `UseShellExecute` property of the `ProcessStartInfo` to true so that it will open the default browser (e.g. if the user installed Opera Mobile, it will use that, not just always force IE).

Comment: I need to be able to have more than one button each linking to a diferent website, so I think I may need to rely on WebBrowser. Only have IE installed on the emulator.